# How can I create a Firebase Dynamic Link that will open an android instant app when clicked?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

So I want to create a link that will open an android instant app when clicked. I have already created a Firebase dynamic link but it opens a web link, not my app. [Here is the current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSaue.png). How should I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

In your app `Manifest.xml` do like this at the `Activity tag` exactly in `Intent filter` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.application.test">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Test">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <!--  here put these lines : -->

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            
            <!-- here you write your dynamic link host and connection type -->
            <!-- I wrote Youtube so when a youtube link clicked, my app will open-->
            <data android:host="https://www.youtube.com" android:scheme="https"/>

            <!--  End -->
            
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

**and you can use these lines to get the clicked url :**

```
    String clickedUrl = getIntent().getDataString();
    webView.loadUrl(clickedUrl); // This webView just an example
```